# Joyful vs Joyous

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology

Is there any difference between the usages of the words joyful and joyous?
E.g. Could you say both "He was uncontrollably joyful." and "He was uncontrollably joyous."?

Comment: "Joyous" usually refers to the event which causes joy, not to the person experiencing it. "Joyful" may refer to either.

Comment: *Difference Between Joyous and Joyful* : http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-joyous-and-joyful/ - ***1***.“Joyful” is often used to describe a person’s feelings of joy or state of happiness. “Joyous,” on the other hand, is best suited when describing events, things, times, and places.
***2***.“Joyful” and “joyous” can be interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a great deal of difference between the two. And from the OED definitions (below) it is difficult to identify any at all. It is interesting that the entries on **joyous** refer the user to **joyful** but not vice-versa.

*Joyous* seems to me a slightly dated word, and has, I believe been used more in a religious sense. It has a ring of the James I Bible about it. My own inclination would be to reserve *joyous* for more sober enjoyment. Whilst a booze-up at the pub might be said to be a *joyful* occasion, when describing a reunion of long-lost relatives *joyous* would seem more apt. I would not be inclined to use *joyous* to describe a person - *joyful* seems the better word.

The [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=joyous%2Cjoyful&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjoyous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjoyful%3B%2Cc0) are interesting, but tell us little, other than that both words have been in long-term decline.

**OED Definitions**

**Joyful**

1. Of persons, their feelings, etc.: Full of joy; having and showing a lively sense of pleasure or satisfaction; elated with gladness, delighted.
2. Of action, speech, looks, etc.: Expressing or manifesting joy; indicative of gladness.

**Joyous**

1. Having a joyful nature or mood; full of glad feeling; blithe, gladsome, buoyant; also, expressive of, or characterized by, joy; = joyful adj. 1,  2.
2. Of things, events, etc.: Inspiring or productive of joy; gladdening, cheerful; = joyful adj. 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, but it would be a little weird to use *joyous* in spoken English. *Joyous* is used chiefly in written English, while *joyful* is common in both written and spoken English

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English defines both *joyful* and *joyous* as "very happy, or likely to make people very happy."