# What is the difference between "wondrous" and "wonderful"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, suffixes

I have done some research, and I have a hypothesis, largely based on an answer to this same question on Quora. First, allow me to state my research. I looked up the definitions of these two words on Merriam Webster. The definitions are close if not synonymous.

- > [wonderful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonderful)
  >
  > 1 : exciting wonder : marvelous, astonishing  · a sight *wonderful* to behold
  >   2 : unusually good : admirable · did a *wonderful* job
- > [wondrous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wondrous)
  >
  > : that is to be marveled at : extraordinary · a *wondrous* feat

The first definition of *wonderful* is quite similar to the definition of *wondrous*. So I don't think we can draw a distinction just using the first sense given for *wonderful*. The second sense, however, is a bit different. There is a difference between something that is "extremely good" and something that excites wonder. The latter is more poetic and emotional.

This [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/When-should-one-use-wondrous-versus-wonderful) seems to touch on this. It claims that the two words are synonymous, but that *wondrous* is better reserved for poetic and emotional situations.

**Hypothesis**

This has led me to form a hypothesis, and I would like to know whether you think it correct. Has the word *wonderful* shed its first meaning and adopted the second? I am referring in particular to the meanings given within the Merriam-Webster definition.

Does *wonderful* have less to do with things that excite wonder, nowadays, in American English, and more to do with things that are extremely good? Does *wondrous* do a better job of capturing that lost meaning of wonderful, i.e. things that excite wonder?

**Second hypothesis**

If *wonderful* has indeed shed its first meaning of "exciting wonder", then I would guess this is because the word is simply too cliché. I would assume the same is true for words like *amazing*, *awesome* and *awful*. It would be more poignant to say that someone was in *awe*, or that something was *awe-inspiring* or *mesmerizing*, as these words are used less often.

Comment: I think your hypothesis may be correct; the devaluing of the commonly used 'wonderful' to its second meaning and the transfer of its primary meaning to the much less used, almost archaic 'wondrous'.

Comment: You should keep in mind that Merriam-Webster lists definitions in historical order, so that the original meaning is always first.  This is not what we usually expect in a dictionary these days, but it is their style.  The first meaning given is definitely not the primary one these days.  This is explained at https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-definitions.

Comment: @Steven Well, I just learned something. Does that mean that, let's say, 90 percent of dictionaries list definitions by their popularity?

Comment: @Zan700 I haven't made a study of it, but I'd say that the vast majority of dictionaries order definitions by most to least common.

Comment: @Steve So if a word is misused a lot, that erroneous meaning will become the first meaning, and thus reinforce the misuse. I do see this happening with some words.

Comment: Since the advent of online dictionaries, words that begin as errors probably find their way into dictionaries faster, and thus become legitimized.  They don't have to worry about having a limited number of pages printed.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Joyful vs Joyous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261610)

Comment: Also related: a previous question that I wrote an answer to, although I don't think it will be too helpful to you: [Nouns to adjectives: “-ous” vs. “-ful”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299396)

Comment: Could any of you please explain any difference between *exciting wonder* and *to be wondered at*… or are you saying *wonder* and *marvel* are not broadly interchangeable?

Comment: See also https://www.writerscentre.com.au/blog/qa-wonderous-vs-wondrous-vs-wonderful/

Answer (score 1):

The subtle differences are explained in the definitions:

wondrous--**that** is to be marveled at; 
wonderful--marvelous, unusually good

"wondrous" focuses on the thing(s) in question;
"wonderful" focuses on the speaker's emotional reaction.

So one may respond to a good suggestion with "that's wonderful", but *not* "that's wondrous."

Or: "That's a wonderful collection" to a friend, but (perhaps) *not* "That's a wondrous collection" to the same friend--though a writer may describe said collection as "a wondrous collection."

Sometimes we see the two used in similar sentences. For all practical purposes, the two mean exactly the same thing. Nonetheless, the subtlety is there:

"the wonderful world of animation" and "the wondrous world of animation"

Answer (score -1):

One word (wonderful) is an adjective, the other(wondrous) an adverb.

This is where KISS comes into play, most wording occurs due to one of two reasons, 1. Laziness, and 2. A desire to be “different” as in one generation specifically modifying linguistic meaning as a symbol of rebellion to another grouping of people’s ie: 
an individual desires to be “different” from which then becomes a “word” due to how popular or strong that diferrencing gap is desired.

KISS meaning Keep It Simple, Stupid.

Comment: Actually "wondrous" is used to good effect in E.B. White's novel Charlotte's Web: "Everybody knew that the Zuckermans had a wondrous pig." I don't think it has to do with rebellion. The two words simply have different meaning, and the acquisition of meaning is probably more often a long story than not.

Comment: The KISS was more in reference to the identification of word difference, your description of the meaning was associated to its being an adverb versus being an adjective, ie: it’s (The word’s) original function.

Comment: Well I think the word is an adjective. I would guess that the adverb should be "wondrously".

Comment: "Wondrous" is both an adjective and an (archaic) adverb (as can be seen in the definition linked in the question, and most other dictionaries). The question is pretty clearly asking about the adjective. The rest of your answer is an opinion, of what I am not sure.

Comment: Actually both are correct Laurel, I just joined the group and the reason was related to words that originated as acronyms, evolving into a discussion of words that evolved from acronyms to words,